# Passing Iterator to method

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm trying to pass an iterator as the argument for a method in Spring Data, but eclipse is telling me that Java is trying to call the plain entity overload of the same method.

```
public void persistLandTiles(List<LandTile> tilesToPersist) {
    landTileRepo.save(tilesToPersist.iterator());

}
```

The error:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method save(U) of type CRUDRepository<T> is not applicable
 for the arguments (Iterator<LandTile>). The inferred type Iterator<LandTile> is not a
 valid substitute for the bounded parameter <U extends LandTile>
```

and the interface methods being called:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CRUDRepository<T> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, Long> {

    /**
     * persists an entity by forwarding to entity.persist()
     * @param entity to be persisted
     * @return the saved entity (being the same reference as the parameter)
     */
    @Transactional
    <U extends T> U save(U entity);


    /**
     * persists the provided entities by forwarding to their entity.persist() methods
     * @param entities to be persisted
     * @return the input iterable
     */
    @Transactional
    <U extends T> Iterable<U> save(Iterable<U> entities);
```

My interface that's being autowired:

```
public interface LandTileRepo extends CRUDRepository<LandTile>, SpatialRepository<LandTile>  {  
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong that it's trying to call the "  U save(U entity);" method instead of the " Iterable save(Iterable entities);" method?

Also, since it looks like the method that accepts an iterator just calls entity.persist() anyway, is there any downside to me just calling save(U entity) in a foreach loop anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong that it's trying to call the " U save(U entity);" method instead of the " Iterable save(Iterable entities);" method?

Well `save(Iterable<U> entities)` clearly isn't valid here, because you have an `Iterator<E>`, not an `Iterable<E>`. They're different types. Given two method overloads which are both invalid for the arguments that you're trying to pass, the compiler has picked one to complain about... it doesn't *really* matter much which it says is invalid, IMO.

It's not clear why you're calling `iterator()` at all, but you should try just changing your code to:

```
public void persistLandTiles(List<LandTile> tilesToPersist) {
    landTileRepo.save(tilesToPersist);    
}
```

After all, `List<E>` extends `Iterable<E>` - so this method call will be valid...

Comment: When I query things I keep dealing with the class "EndResult<LandTile>" which only returns an Iterator, so I keep having to convert Iterators to Lists, and I thought they were only accepting Iterators too.